# Asynchronous while loop update observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, asynchronous, data-binding

I have a problem with a program that I'm writing. What I want is a loop that runs as long as the program is running, with 30 seconds timespan. I want this loop to update the an ObservableCollection so that the news show up at the top of the window when there is a new one.

I've stripped down the code so only the most important parts are for your disposal. If this code would have worked, I would have seen a new item in the observable collection of the news that is added. This is not however how it works. With this code I only get the first one.

What is missing?

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ObservableCollection<News> list = new ObservableCollection<News>();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LoopFunction(list));
    NewsListView.ItemsSource = list.OrderByDescending(a => a.Date);
}
public ObservableCollection<News> LoopFunction (ObservableCollection<News> list)
{
    while (true)
    {
        list.Add(new News() { Date = "2016-12-12", From = "DIRECT:", Title = "This program is not working", Content = "We have to fix it." });
        Thread.Sleep(30000);
    }
}
public class News
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you for all your comments. Here's how I got it working.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ObservableCollection<News> list = new ObservableCollection<News>();

    // Fetches news when the program initiates
    FetchNews(list);

    // Fetches news every 30 seconds
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    timer.Tick += (s, args) => FetchNews(list);
    timer.Start();
}
public void FetchNews (ObservableCollection<News> list)
{
    list.Add(new News() { Date = "2016-12-12", From = "DIRECT:", Title = "This program is working", Content = "We have fixed it." });
    NewsListView.ItemsSource = list.OrderByDescending(a => a.Date);
}
public class News
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The primary problem is that OrderByDescending returns a new enumerable that sorts when enumerated, however it does not provide the view with collection changed events. The view does not know it should be updated. Another issue that is likely to come up is that an ObservableCollection bound to a view must be updated on the UI thread.

Comment: LoopFunction does not return ObservableCollection<News>.  You would need concurrent OC and there is not one.  Even after all that I don't think  this would work.  Not sure what you trying to do here but  look for another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just use DispatcherTimer instead of doing anything asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

As mike said as you are using OrderByDescending the NewsListView is not being notified for the 'list' collection changed.

Also if you use

```
NewsListView.ItemsSource = list;
```

You will still get exception as you are updating the collection in non UI thread. But yes, if you are using .NET 4.5 you can update the collection in non UI thread, what you need to do is following,

```
    ObservableCollection<News> list = new ObservableCollection<News>();
    BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(list, listLock);
```

and also you need to define the lock variable somewhere in the class,

```
private object listLock = new object();
```